# Why implicit casting from object to reference is allowed?

Tags: c++, casting, reference, type-conversion

Let's have an exaple:

```
Foo& Foo::operator+=(Foo val)
{
    // logic...
    return *this;
}

Foo operator+(Foo v1, Foo v2)
{
    return v1+=v2;
}
```

If an expression `v1+=v2` is of a type `Foo&`, why it can be used as a return value of a function returning `Foo`? Where is a cast performed? Does a fact an `operator+=` is implemented as a member of `Foo` make any difference?

Comment: References don't exist they are just alias for the object.

Comment: Both overloaded operators should take `const` references as parameters, instead of taking their parameters by value, unless you like burning helpless electrons by making useless copies of objects all over the place. This does mean that the `+` operator needs to make an explicit copy, but that's a small price to pay for saving many more suffering electrons elsewhere.

Comment: In this exaple I can't make `v1` a reference, because I want to use `+=` operator to modify it, but don't want original object to be modified.

Comment: @Nightcat Then you can make a local copy, use `+=` on it, and return it. One reason to do that is that return value optimization does not apply if the thing being returned is a function parameter. But it is not uncommon to take one of the two parameters by value and return it like you have done.

Comment: What you're talking about is an **implicit conversion**. There is no such thing as an implicit cast. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. Casts are always explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ lets you use a reference in place of an object. In situations when an object is returned by value (i.e. by copying) the compiler is making a new object to be returned anyway; it simply assigns that object the value from the reference that you are returning, i.e.

```
Foo operator+(Foo v1, Foo v2) {
    Foo ret(v1+=v2); // << This is done implicitly
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Is that mean `v1` parameter is copied twice, first by function call, second by implicit coping constructor call?

Comment: @Nightcat Right, that's what's happening. Of course you have complete control over what gets copied (e.g. you could mark items `const Foo& v2` if you wanted to avoid copying there), so the compiler views this copying as intentional.